# Prove using power series that $e^{z_1+z_2}=e^{z_1}e^{z_2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have tried to prove it expanding the power series but it seems very complex and not doable. Is there any simple trick to prove this?

Thanks

Comment: It is doable using power series: remember the binomial expansion for $(z_1+z_2)^n$.

Comment: yes, but it is very difficult.

Comment: Really, it isn't.

Comment: Maybe consider the Cauchy summation?

Comment: @Vim No, Cauchy summation  has nothing to do with it. It's entirely straighforward: Write $e^{z_1+z_2}$ as a power series and then apply the binomial theorem to $(z_1+z_2)^n$.